# How can i get this data format using `reduce` or `forEach` in `JavaScript`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following data where it is being used in stats.

this is the input Data:

```
 data=[
       {  date: '2018-01-08',
         assignment: 'java',
         count: 2 },
       { date: '2018-01-04',
         assignment: 'java',
         count: 3 },
       { date: '2018-01-04',
         assignment: 'javaScript',
         count: 2 },
       { date: '2017-12-18',
         assignment: 'java',
         count: 2 },
       { date: '2017-11-24',
         assignment: 'java',
         count: 2 },
       { date: '2018-01-02',
         assignment: 'javaScript',
         count: 2 },....]
```

My attempt:

```
let dataColln = data.map((e)=>{
   let obj = {};
   obj.date = e.date;
   obj[e.assignment] = e.count;
   return obj;
});
```

this is the expected output:

```
 [{ 
     date:2018-01-08,
     java: 2
   },
   { 
     date:2018-01-04,
     java: 3,
     javaScript: 2
   },
   { 
     date:2018-01-02,
     javaScript: 2
   },...]
```

How can i achieve the above format by using javaScript `forEach` or `reduce` methods?

I was able to get the count assigned to the name.
I also tried `groupBy` and `uniqBy` methods in lodash.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of those methods on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2)? Have you tried writing the code?

Comment: @suryateja what you can do with forEach is override the object itself. So it would look like `array.forEach((obj) => { obj[obj.assignment] = obj.count; delete obj.count})`. But I would suggest using `.map`. Your code should work fine. Also, reduce is not meant for such manipulation so its better you avoid it

Comment: you could use a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Map` for collecting the values and render the result by taking the values.

This proposal features

- [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for collecting items ans for an access via a key and [`Map#set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) and [`Map#get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) for setting a new entry or getting an entry,
- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating the given data,
- a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for getting properties of an object as variables,
- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with a default object for assigning single properties with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for an object.
- Later take the values of the map with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var data = [{ date: '2018-01-08', assignment: 'java', count: 2 }, { date: '2018-01-04', assignment: 'java', count: 3 }, { date: '2018-01-04', assignment: 'javaScript', count: 2 }, { date: '2017-12-18', assignment: 'java', count: 2 }, { date: '2017-11-24', assignment: 'java', count: 2 }, { date: '2018-01-02', assignment: 'javaScript', count: 2 }],
    map = new Map,
    result;

data.forEach(({ date, assignment, count }) =>
    map.set(date, Object.assign(map.get(date) || { date }, { [assignment]: count }))
);

result = [...map.values()]
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```